# Setting the selected value of bootstrap dropdown button on postback in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have built a bootstrap search with a dropdown button that allows selection of the search type, for example first name or last name.  I have this mostly working and am able to pass the search type and string into my model without problem.  The problem I have is that after the search button is clicked and the postback occurs the dropdown selector returns to its default setting, and I would like to display the search type that is placed back into the hiddenfield during postback.

The hidden field and the search string are populated on postback, but I'm unsure of the best method of setting the value of the dropdown.

```
 <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-All-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_All_concept">@SiteStrings.FilterBy</span> <span id="txt" class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">@SiteStrings.All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#level">@SiteStrings.Level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#UCI">UCI</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#firstname">@SiteStrings.FirstName</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#lastname">@SiteStrings.LastName</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.search_All_param)
            @*<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_All_String" placeholder="Search term..." />*@
            @Html.EditorFor(s => s.search_All_String, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search for..." } })
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ternary to apply the active class:

```
<li class="@(Model.search_All_param == SiteStrings.All ? "active" : null)">
    <a href="#">@SiteStrings.All</a>
</li>
```

Rinse and repeat for each of the items in the dropdown.

Comment: SiteStrings.All could be welsh, so this approach wouldn't work. The Model will contain #lastname for example taken from the a href.  I tried <li class="@(Model.search_All_param == "lastname" ? "active" : null)"><a href="#lastname">@SiteStrings.LastName</a></li> which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If I change to be this, <li class="active"><a href="#lastname">@SiteStrings.LastName</a></li> when you dropdown it is active, but it is not displayed in the text portion of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Guess there are better ways, but this gives me exactly what I need...

```
<div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {

        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-All-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_All_concept">
                        @{
                            switch(@Model.search_All_param)
                            {
                                case "level":
                                    @SiteStrings.Level
                                break;

                                case "firstname":
                                    @SiteStrings.FirstName
                                break;

                                case "lastname":
                                    @SiteStrings.LastName
                                break;

                                default:
                                    @SiteStrings.FilterBy
                                    break;
                            }
                        }       
                    </span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">@SiteStrings.All</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#level">@SiteStrings.Level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#firstname">@SiteStrings.FirstName</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#lastname">@SiteStrings.LastName</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.search_All_param)
            @Html.EditorFor(s => s.search_All_String, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search for..." } })
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
```